# Set locals value for Cocoon partial using Jquery, Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cocoon-gem

I am creating simple Quiz app. So far I have implemented Cocoon gem that allows creating nested forms. Everything works great, except I would like to pass some variable to Cocoon partial.

**Problem**: I can send  static value without problem, but I would like to pass dynamic value that is calculated in Jquery.

My code:

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to_add_association 'Pievienot atbildi', f, :answers,render_options: {locals: { question_id: 'Holmes' }}, :class=>"btn btn-default" %>


<script type="text/javascript">
          var n = $( ".reg_input_question" ).length;
          alert(n); 
</script>
```

**_answer_fields.html.erb**

```
  <%= f.radio_button :correct_one, false, :checked => false, :name=> question_id %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "Dzēst atbildi", f , :class=>"btn btn-default text-danger"%>
```

I want to send **n** variable from **index.html.erb** page to **_answers_fields** partial. I can send static value "Holmes", but I have no idea how to
set `{locals: { question_id: 'Holmes' }}` value to something other using script.

I found [Great example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637242/passing-javascript-variables-to-rails-partials) to do that with regular partials, but as I am using Cocoon partial handling I can't do as in that example.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

I have 3 nested models test, question and answer. First I am creating Question with:

```
 <%= link_to_add_association "Pievienot jautājumu", f, :questions, :class=>"btn btn-default" %>
```

When Question is created I can create answers with code above. Answers partial consists of answer text and correct_one boolean. I am using radio_button to allow to select just one from newly created answers as correct_one.

Problem: When I create multiple questions their answers share the same radio_button name "Holmes". That leads to problem when user has selected correct answer for first question and then clicks second question answer previous selection is cleared.

**I want like this:**

```
1. Question
   <%= f.radio_button :correct_one, false, :checked => false, :name=> 1 %>
   <%= f.radio_button :correct_one, false, :checked => false, :name=> 1 %>

2. Question
   <%= f.radio_button :correct_one, false, :checked => false, :name=> 2 %>
   <%= f.radio_button :correct_one, false, :checked => false, :name=> 2 %>
```

**Currently I have like this:**

```
1. Question
   <%= f.radio_button :correct_one, false, :checked => false, :name=> "Holmes" %>
   <%= f.radio_button :correct_one, false, :checked => false, :name=> "Holmes" %>

2. Question
   <%= f.radio_button :correct_one, false, :checked => false, :name=> "Holmes" %>
   <%= f.radio_button :correct_one, false, :checked => false, :name=> "Holmes" %>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I think you need a checkbox instead. A radio-button will allow you to specify different values for the same field (and select only one). You want to indicate if an answer is correct or not, so you would have to save a value for each answer, no? I get the radio-button makes sure you automatically deselect the other values, but in this case it will not save correctly to the database. I think you need something like this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947569/how-to-automatically-uncheck-a-checkbox-if-another-checkbox-is-checked-through-j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found way around to this problem:

in **_answers_fields.html.erb**

```
      $('input[name="Holmes"]').each(function () { 

        var id = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/);

        $(this).attr('name', id);

      });
```

Basically, this script loops through all answer fields with name "Holmes" and changes name attribute to part of id(As id of each input is resource specific - each question id is passed to nested resource).

Ugly approach, but it does work as I need.